# Unable to serve static files using Nginx server (Nginx Error 403 Forbidden)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, permissions

I have Nginx 1.18.0 installed on Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to serve (many) custom HTML files via Nginx. The HTML files contain animation of online images and mapping. Some HTML files also have associated JS and CSS files.

Instead of using defaults, I created a server block `my_domain` like this:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/my_domain/html
chown -R my_username /var/www/my_domain/html
chmod -R 755 /var/www/my_domain
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Then, as a test, I put `my_html1.html` (here, no associated JS/CSS) inside `/var/www/my_domain/html` and tried to access via Mozilla Firefox browser. I am getting `403 Error Forbidden`.

I googled the error and tried suggestions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808813/nginx-serve-static-file-and-got-403-forbidden), but so far, no success. For example, I tried assigning the ownership of `my_domain` directory to www-data user, but didn't help.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_domain
```

This is how my `nginx.conf` look like.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}
http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_domain`

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/my_domain/html;
        index my_html1.html;

        server_name my_domain www.my_domain;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                autoindex on;
                autoindex_exact_size off;
        }
}
```

Can somebody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Answer is always in the `error.log`.

Comment: The error log tells about permission denied, specifically, `*16 open() "/var/www/my_domain/html/my_html_file.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: my_domain, request: "GET /my_html_file.html HTTP/1.1",` but, i guess, this is also clear from browser's 403 error.

Comment: Then nginx merely lacks *read/execute* permission on directories and *read* on files.

Comment: Did you mean user `www-data` lacks these permissions?  so, `chown 755 -R www-data path/to/directory` is this what i need?

Comment: I am being careful in giving unnecessary permissions and want to avoid chmod 777. Care to post the suggested answer?

Comment: please share the output of `ls -Rl var/www/my_domain/html/`